# mesos-slave can not connect No credentials provided error

Tags: connect, mesos, master-slave, mesosphere

I am new to `mesos`.

After starting `mesos-master`, I tried to connect `mesos-slave` with the following command

```
 /usr/sbin/mesos-slave --ip=192.192.7.180 --master=192.192.7.19:5050 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos/work/int --no-systemd_enable_support
```

It is not connecting to master. It is throwing the following error

> No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No credentials provided meaning you are trying to load a slave which is on a different network which is not configured in mesos config files.

once you register it then you can add it.

for the example sake try

for master

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh –ip=127.0.0.1 –work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

for slave

```
./bin/mesos-slave.sh –master=127.0.0.1:5050 –work_dir=/tmp/mesos –no-systemd_enable_support
```

open browser

```
localhost:5050
```

if all the steps are followed properly you should find a Mesos dashboard [more details](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/building/)